# Boot error when update to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I recently updated my system to Ubuntu 14.04 and now I can no longer boot into any form of graphical interface. I can access the recovery and then resume boot into a basic terminal and everything seems to be working fine. I don't know if the graphics drivers are to blame or if its a dependency that's broken that I got an error on. I was on the AMD proprietary drivers (I believe 13.10? I can't remember the version) so it might not have compatibility with the update. If so could someone link me to a guide on how to concert back over to open source drivers to get it back and operating. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your old driver is probably not compatible on 14.04. 
You should try reinstalling or revert to the radeon drivers.

Follow the instructions on the cchtml.com wiki:
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide